# Visual Studio Code Go To Definition not working properly

Tags: visual-studio-code, editor, omnisharp, go-to-definition

I'm working on a simple *Node.js* project with *NextJS* in which the ***Go To Definition*** doesn't work properly in *vscode*.

I made a small [video](https://youtu.be/O_avWLIEm3k) with the difference between *Visual Studio Code* and *WebStorm*, in which *WebStorm*, works perfectly out of the box, without any extension installed.

Does someone know why is this not working in the case shown in the video?
Want to mention that other ***Go To Definition*** are working ok, eg. for imports or other local variables.

There are the installed extension *vscode*:

```
Extensions installed on WSL: Ubuntu:
2gua.rainbow-brackets
aaron-bond.better-comments
alefragnani.Bookmarks
Anjali.clipboard-history
BendixMa.dart-data-class-generator
BriteSnow.vscode-toggle-quotes
christian-kohler.path-intellisense
Dart-Code.dart-code
Dart-Code.flutter
DavidAnson.vscode-markdownlint
dbaeumer.vscode-eslint
deque-systems.vscode-axe-linter
eamodio.gitlens
EditorConfig.EditorConfig
esbenp.prettier-vscode
FelixAngelov.bloc
formulahendry.auto-close-tag
formulahendry.auto-rename-tag
Gruntfuggly.todo-tree
IbrahimCesar.ibrahimcesar-nextjs-developer-pack
jeroen-meijer.pubspec-assist
jpoissonnier.vscode-styled-components
k--kato.intellij-idea-keybindings
leodevbro.blockman
luanpotter.dart-import
MariusAlchimavicius.json-to-ts
meganrogge.template-string-converter
mhutchie.git-graph
mikestead.dotenv
ms-vscode.vscode-typescript-tslint-plugin
naco-siren.gradle-language
naumovs.color-highlight
oderwat.indent-rainbow
Orta.vscode-jest
PKief.material-icon-theme
PulkitGangwar.nextjs-snippets
quicktype.quicktype
rangav.vscode-thunder-client
richie5um2.vscode-sort-json
shardulm94.trailing-spaces
shd101wyy.markdown-preview-enhanced
sleistner.vscode-fileutils
streetsidesoftware.code-spell-checker
VisualStudioExptTeam.vscodeintellicode
```

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem with [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23).

- For [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) `go-to-definition` did not work;
- the context menu lacks the option `go-to-definition`.

For [java](/questions/tagged/java) the `go-to-definition` did work as expected (see image below)

[image: vs-code-go-to-definition-java-works]

I first did fix [Visual Studio Code 1.73.1 trouble - object not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75323687/) but problems still remained

#### Fix `go-to-definition` for [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)

[Omnisharp Wiki - Troubleshooting: 'The .NET Core SDK cannot be located.' errors](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/wiki/Troubleshooting:-%27The-.NET-Core-SDK-cannot-be-located.%27-errors) gave these hints

1. check the path to dotnet with `C:\where.exe dotnet`

   - In my case two paths were returned:
   - `C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe` and
   - `C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\dotnet.exe`
2. check the environment variable path `C:\>echo %PATH%`

   - In my case i had two entries for both paths above
3. change the environment variable with `C:\SystemPropertiesAdvanced.exe`

   - i removed the path to for  x86 dotnet.exe

From the [Troubleshooting](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/wiki/Troubleshooting:-%27The-.NET-Core-SDK-cannot-be-located.%27-errors) page

> In 64-bit environments the .NET SDK will fail to be discovered if the
> 32-bit dotnet path comes before the 64-bit dotnet path in the
> Environment PATH variable. Try removing the 32-bit path entirely from
> your PATH variable and relaunch VS Code to see if your issue is
> resolved.

#### Omnisharp settings

I also added the path in the omnisharp settings

[image: Visual Studio Code - Settings for omnisharp set to dotnet path]

What did i do to fix it

1. Removed the environment variable to x86 version
2. added the path to the omnisharp settings
3. rebooted the system

#### What about `go-to-definition` for [nodejs](/questions/tagged/nodejs) or [nextjs](/questions/tagged/nextjs)?

I would recommend to check if you have two versions installed as well and if you can point the extension to the correct version.