# Visual Studio Code 1.73.1 trouble - object not defined

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, .net-7.0, omnisharp

#### Initial

Recently after upgrading to .Net 7 and Visual Studio Code 1.73.1 the IDE [visual-studio-code](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-code) shows error message like

- [CS0518](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0518) Predefined type 'type' is not defined or imported
- [CS0400](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0400) The type or namespace name 'identifier' could not be found in the global namespace (are you missing an assembly reference?)
- [CS0246](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0246) The type or namespace name 'type/namespace' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

##### Steps to reproduce

1. install .Net 7.0
2. install Visual Studio Code 1.73.1
3. open `cmd.exe` (as admin or as user <-- i picked admin)
4. inside `cmd.exe` go to a folder for instance `cd C:\dev\`
5. run `dotnet new console --use-program-main -o IdeTrouble`
6. cd into folder `c:\dev\IdeTrouble`
7. run `dotnet run`
8. run `code .`  this open VSCode and the project IdeTrouble
9. run `dotnet build` from a terminal

```bash
C:\dev\IdeTrouble>dotnet build
MSBuild version 17.4.0+18d5aef85 for .NET
  Determining projects to restore...
  All projects are up-to-date for restore.
  IdeTrouble -> C:\dev\stackoverflow\IdeTrouble
                                            \bin\Debug\net7.0
                                              \IdeTrouble.dll
Build succeeded.
```

##### Result

- Expected: the IDE reports no errors
- Actual: lots of errors (see screen below)

In the screen you can see that [rider](/questions/tagged/rider) shows no errors but [visual-studio-code](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-code) 1.73.1 does show lots of errors.

#### Question: How do i fix this?

I would like that visual studio code shows no errors and problems and finds all the types and namespaces it needs.

[image]

##### Code

This is the code but running `dotnet new console --use-program-main` is all you need to reproduce this annoyance on my machine.

```cs
    namespace IdeTrouble;
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
        }
    }
```

This is one of the errors

```json
[{
    "resource": "/c:/dev/IdeTrouble
                    /obj/Debug/net7.0
                    /.NETCoreApp,Version=v7.0.AssemblyAttributes.cs",
    "owner": "csharp",
    "code": "CS0400",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found 
                in the global namespace 
                (are you missing an assembly reference?)
                [IdeTrouble]",
    "source": "csharp",
    "startLineNumber": 4,
    "startColumn": 20,
    "endLineNumber": 4,
    "endColumn": 26
}]
```

#### OmniSharp Error - Update

After rebooting an opening the output windows (<kbd>CTRL + SHIFT + U</kbd>) i saw this

```
[fail]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
        Version 7.0.100 of the .NET SDK requires at least version 17.3.0 
        of MSBuild. The current available version of MSBuild is 17.1.0.7505.
        Change the .NET SDK specified in global.json to an older version 
        that requires the MSBuild version currently available. 

[fail]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
        The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk' specified could not be found. 

[fail]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Failed to load project file 'c:\dev\...\ObjectNotDefined.csproj'.
```

To my understanding of [MSBuild](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild?view=vs-2022) the needed msbuild version should be part of the sdk. Running `dotnet --list-sdks` returns this:

```
C:\Windows\System32>dotnet --list-sdks
3.1.120 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
3.1.426 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
5.0.408 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
6.0.113 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
7.0.100 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
```

- What am i misssing?
- Is msbuild part of [these build tools](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2022)-download?

Comment: Post your code as *text*, not images. VS Code is just the editor. The errors come from the compiler. Images can't be copied, compiled and tested

Comment: I added the code (see above). But all you need is to create a new project using `dotnet new console --use-program-main`.

Comment: There is obviously problem with your VS Code setup, so your repro will not work for those who do not have problems with it.

Comment: No repro then. If I create a new console application and run `dotnet run`, it runs. What you posted isn't a compiler error either

Comment: Agree with @GuruStron, Could not replicate this. My VSCode version is 1.74.3 and no errors appear.

Comment: Do you get errors if you type `dotnet build` in the console?

Comment: No everything looks good - see above.

Comment: Is this error specific to the name "ObjectNotDefined", that is: Can you perform the steps successfully with a different name?

Comment: @Peter: I can pick another name for the project. Just tried this `dotnet new console --use-program-main -o IdeTrouble`. The result is the same

Comment: Have you tried to reboot? Also check omnisharp/c# extension plugin settings.

Comment: @GuruStron I will reboot now - be right back. What do i have to check for in the `omnisharp/c# extension plugin settings`?

Comment: @surfmuggle I don't remember exactly. Sometimes installing latest version of VS helps (on Windows obviously). Also possibly specifying dotnet path can help. Check `useModernDotnet` also

Comment: Have you tried to re-create the contents of the ".vscode" directory by using Ctrl+Shift+P: ".NET: Generate Assets for Build and Debug" ?

Comment: No i did not. My assumption is that having two paths varibles one for 32bit the other for 64bit  was the cause (see update below). It seems that now everything is working as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated [C# extension](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode) for Visual Studio Code and now got an error "dotnet.exe" could not be found so i added the path to the sdk

```json
"omnisharp.sdkPath": "C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\sdk"
```

to the omnisharp config settings

[image: Visual Studio Code - settings omnisharp 1]

and also

[image: Visual Studio Code - settings omnisharp 2]

#### Update

The [Troubleshooting: 'The .NET Core SDK cannot be located.' errors](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/wiki/Troubleshooting:-%27The-.NET-Core-SDK-cannot-be-located.%27-errors) advised to check where dotnet is located

```bash
C:\>where.exe dotnet
```

and possibly change the path

> In 64-bit environments the .NET SDK will fail to be discovered if the
> 32-bit dotnet path comes before the 64-bit dotnet path in the
> Environment PATH variable. Try removing the 32-bit path entirely from
> your PATH variable and relaunch VS Code to see if your issue is
> resolved.

The command `where.exe dotnet` returned this

```bash
C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\dotnet.exe
```

To check the path you can enter these commands

```bash
C:\>SystemPropertiesAdvanced.exe

C:\>echo %PATH%
```

I deleted the `x86-path` and set both paths `sdk` and `dotnetPath` in the omnisharp settings.

```json
"omnisharp.sdkPath": "C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\sdk"
"omnisharp.dotnetPath": "C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\"
```

This resolved all the reported problems and also [Visual Studio Code `go-to-definition` does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75420489/819887)